# Is it okay to ask multiple questions at once?

Tags: discusión

I know this might sound ridiculous to ask? But right now for examples, I have about ten questions to ask. And I thought some of them can just be answered with a yes or no. So posting these questions separately is just a waste of time, space, energy.

Also, is there a place to ask really trivial questions??

Answer (score 2):

You can make as many posts as once as you want.  But each post must contain only one post.  There are a number of reasons for this.

1. We are a Question-and-Answer site, not a forum, and we intend to make our content useful to future visitors.

   If a single post contains multiple questions, it is much more difficult for future visitors with the same or similar questions to find the answers they need.

   By limiting each post to a single question, each post is focused and specific, and much more searchable.
2. If you ask multiple questions, it becomes difficult or impossible to select the best (single) answer.  One answer may address one question better, and another answer may address another part better.  As a general rule, questions here should have a single correct answer, so that this answer can be the single accepted answer.  Asking multiple questions in a single post makes this difficult or impossible.
3. If you ask multiple questions, it is difficult to vote. One question may be good and deserve an upvote, another may be bad and deserve a downvote, and yet another may be off-topic and need to be closed. If they are all lumped together, they cannot be addressed individually as necessary.

So in summary: Always ask only one question per post.  Posts with multiple questions are routinely closed as 'Too broad' until they can be split up.